# Create only certain types of Apps in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, security

Is there a way to restrict users to create only certain types of Apps in SharePoint, for example let's say that I just want to allow them just to create Document Libraries and not Lists, Calendars, etc.

Do I have a way to restrict that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two ways

1. Update Site Template and remove unwanted list types. This way user will never see them in the add new app dialog
2. Use Web Event Receiver and cancel the event. This approach is not user friendly

Once more workaround is to hide unwanted app from the new app dialog using JavaScript.